# limited size queue

Tags: c++, boost, queue, std

I need a queue on *n* items where insertion of (*n*+1)<sup>th</sup> item removes the 0<sup>th</sup> item and insertion can only be made on the "back".
Is there any such structure already there in boost or standard library?

Comment: Can you give size limitation there ?

Comment: I'd hope so; a circular buffer of unbounded size would be indistinguishable from a vector ;)

Comment: Oh! Ya I see. Thats it. Thanks

Comment: @Rook: shocking! It should be indistinguishable from a deque.

Comment: Oh, I do apologise. I'll go and stand in the corner and think about what I've done.

Comment: @DiproSen: dunno, I could read the documentation for you...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [`boost::circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) wrapped by a [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), something like this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

typedef std::queue<my_type, boost::circular_buffer<my_type>> my_queue;
const int n = 3;
...
my_queue q(boost::circular_buffer<my_type>(n));
q.push(1);
q.push(2);
q.push(3);
q.push(4); // queue now contains 2,3,4
```

Comment: but why wrapp it in a `queue` ? why not bare `circular_queue`

Comment: @DiproSen: the only purpose of `std::queue` (ever), is to prevent yourself from accessing the underlying container other than by pushing one end and reading/popping the other. You're the one who said you need one.

Comment: Now that's really neat, I must say! :)